# module names in requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

When I load a module using requirejs, do I use the file name or the variable name defined in the module.

For example in the module definition `mymodule.js`

```
define( function () {

    var module = 'Hello World!';

    return module;

});
```

And then in the consuming module `foo.js`

Do I call it with:

```
require( [mymodule], function (module) {
    console.log(module);
});
```

Or

```
require( [mymodule], function (mymodule) {
    console.log(mymodule);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Technically you can call it whatever you like, but one limitation of just using `module` is what do you do when you have two modules? `module2`? It's better (and more common) to name the parameter to match the module name:

```
require(['ajaxloader', 'modules/carousel', 'jquery'], function(ajaxloader, carousel, $){

});
```

In the above example you can see that even if the module has a path it makes sense to just use the module name. And there are always exceptions, in this case using `$` instead of `jquery`.